# Creating an array from documentsDirectory includes ends with .MOV

Tags: objective-c

I want to create a NSArray from my app sandbox's documentsDirectory's includes. It includes so many files, but my array will only be by the ones ends with .MOV.

Can you help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of options using the `NSFileManager`.

```
NSString *path = @"<dir_path>";

//Option 1 using directory enumerator
NSDirectoryEnumerator *direnum = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:path];
NSMutableArray *movfiles = [NSMutableArray array];
while(NSString *file = [direnum nextObject])
{
    if([[file pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"MOV"])
        [movfiles addObject:movfiles];
}
```

---

```
//Option 2 case insensitive using a predicate
NSError *error;
NSArray *dircontents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&error];
if(error)
{
    //Handle error
}
else
{
    dircontents = [dircontents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
                   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pathExtension ==[c] %@", @"mov"]];
}
```

Comment: I am going to let you discover this one on your own in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Thats all I did when I answered this question :).