# Count Number of Files with Extension in iPhone Documents

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I can think of ways to do this with taking the array:

```
NSArray *doc_contents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
```

and doing string parsing to find the extension, but that seems like a roundabout way of doing this. Is there a cut and dry way to count the number of .jpg files in my iPhone app documents directory?

Thanks.

**EDIT** Solved here: [Creating an array from documentsDirectory includes ends with .MOV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447277/creating-an-array-from-documentsdirectory-includes-ends-with-mov)

Comment: same as this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032541/nspredicate-endswith-multiple-files

Comment: Yes and this one actually pertained more to a single extension: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447277/creating-an-array-from-documentsdirectory-includes-ends-with-mov

Comment: Previous searches gave me nothing. Once I learned of NSPredicate, searching was more productive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these links are great resources for this problem.

This one deals with the situation when you have multiple file extensions you are looking for:
[NSPredicate endswith multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032541/nspredicate-endswith-multiple-files)

This one is focused on just one extension:
[Creating an array from documentsDirectory includes ends with .MOV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447277/creating-an-array-from-documentsdirectory-includes-ends-with-mov)

Both methods use the NSPredicate class.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the application called "Xcode Statistician". It's really clean and wills how you tons of other information like the total number of lines and such.